# Changes are not getting reflected in Ionic 2 app even after successful build

Tags: ionic2

I am facing a very weird issue here and I could do with some help from you guys!My Ionic2 App is running some previous build.The app was running fine but all of a sudden whatever changes I am making, how small it might be is not reflecting although build it is showing successful. I am running my app on Visual Studio Emulator for Android and running the following commands for running the app in emulator:

```
ionic cordova build android
ionic cordova run android
```

Even, I also tried deleting the platforms folder and adding it again:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

After this I built and ran it again, but of no use. 
Adding to this, I uninstalled and then again reinstalled ionic and cordova in my system to make sure that I have the latest versions of both in my system(3.5.0 and 7.0.1 respectively), but again didn't help.
Someone please suggest what I can do here!

Comment: Change the bundle id of your app from config.xml and deploy it to real device..